# Docusign Embedded Signing - Can i give a different return url to be shown when session gets expired?

Tags: docusignapi

I have integrated Docusign embedded signing in my Portal. Now i am using a return url to be shown when user signs the document but the problem is that same return url is shown when the embedded signing session expires. Is there any way i can specify different return url for the expire session case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there's only one return_url.

But it includes the `event` query parameter (QP) to tell your app how the embedded signing ceremony ended.

Also note that just because the `event` QP says that the envelope was signed, you should take that with a grain of salt, since a bad guy could be spoofing your app. So before you make a business decision based on whether the person signed or not, ask DocuSign for the envelope's status or refer to a notification from a webhook.